# Modify queries to Prepared Statements and execute

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a legacy app which executes queries in the following way.Queries are formed by String concatenation and put into a Hashmap with a key.

`hashMap = [key1=query1,key2=query2,...]`

(Each query is different)

Then the map is iterated for all the keys and query is executed with Statement and the result set is put in a map and returned.

```
while(keys.hasnext()){
key=keys.next();
query = hashMap.get(key).toString();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
Resultset rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
}
```

I want to change these as prepared statements.But I'm not able to come up with a way to pass parameters for each query since each query is different and set it here with setString or setInt. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `List` of `HashMap`

Result:

```
hashMap = 
[
'key1' = {'query' = '..queries','statement' = '...statements'},
'key2' = {'query' = '..queries','statement' = '...statements'}
];
hashmap.forEach(map-> {
    PreparedStatement stmt= con.prepareStatement(map.get("statement")));
    Resultset rs = stmt.executeQuery(map.get("query"));
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more.